# Check user account model type

Tags: django, django-users

What would be the best way to check model type of an account that has extended Django User model?
I have two types of User accounts (students and teachers, let say) that extend django User model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
     student_bd = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     student_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     ...

class Teacher(models.Model):
     teacher_bd = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     teacher_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     ...
```

So, how can i know if request.user is Student or Teacher?

Comment: `isinstance(request.user,Student)` ?

Comment: That won't work because request.user is always a User instance.

Comment: This is why i test it against the sub class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `User` model and want to check if that model corresponds to either a `Teacher` or a `Student` model, you will need to get the corresponding row from each the tables:

```
try:
    Student.objects.get(student_user=request.user)
    is_student = True
except Student.DoesNotExist:
    is_student = False
```

And the same for the teacher. `is_student` and `is_teacher` will tell you if the `User` is a `Student` or a `Teacher` respectively. This will also work in the odd case if a user is both a student *and* a teacher :) Not useful in this case, but thought it'd help with other roles in a school.

Comment: And before you ask, no, there's no way to do that without querying the DB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you've helped me. This is what i've done: `Student.objects.filter(student_id=user.id).first()` - it returns object or None.

Comment: @LjubisaLivac please revise your code, because it will produce wrong results. You can do it your way, but with a small change: `Student.objects.filter(student__student_user_id=user.id).first()`. What you are doing is to compare the student ID with the user ID, which is not what you want. The revised code above compares the (request) user ID with the student's user ID.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, i didn't notice that! Thank you again

Answer (score 3):

There is no data about the `Student` and `Teacher` models saved in the `User` table, so you'll have to query for the related object.

If you don't need the actual profile (`Student` or `Teacher` object), the fastest way is to use the `exists()` function on the related set:

```
if request.user.student_set.exists():
    # student
elif request.user.teacher_set.exists():
    # teacher
```

If you know you're going to need the profile object later on, it would be faster to fetch the results and check for an existing object in Python:

```
if request.user.student_set.all():
    # do something with student_set
elif request.user.teacher_set.all():
    # do something with teacher_set
```

**Side note:**
If your user shouldn't ever have more than one `Student` or `Teacher` object related, it might be a better idea to use a `OneToOneField` instead of a `ForeignKey`. That way, you don't have to bother with `all()` etc, but you can just access the related model instance with `user.student` or `user.teacher`. This will also allow you to use `select_related`, so that both the user object and the student or teacher object are fetched in a single query.

Comment: Kudos, didn't know you can go through related objects that way. Makes my answer look... rudimentary. +1 from me.

Comment: @knbk, thank you for your thorough answer, and for side note. Eduardo answered first so i have to accept his answer as correct. BTW, i don't know why but Django says that `'User' object has no attribute 'student_set'`.

Comment: @LjubisaLivac Which version of Django are you using? The default name could be different, but you can always specify a related name: `student_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='students')`. I always specify a related name, as it avoids a lot of confusion.